# Force Ansible to throw out error when vars is missing in yml?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to force Ansible when replacing the var in yml files, which is undefined, throw out an error instead silently replaced by an empty string?

Answer (score 10):

Add this line to the `[defaults]` section of your ansible.cfg:

```
error_on_undefined_vars = True
```

You'll now get an error message if a variable is undefined.

Comment: I believe that option requires 1.3, which is coming soon but has not yet been released.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible. Check the online documentation, under [accessing complex variable data](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement).

An example is provided to do exactly that:

```
tasks:
    - shell: echo "I've got '{{ foo }}' and am not afraid to use it!"
      when: foo is defined

    - fail: msg="Bailing out: this play requires 'bar'"
      when: bar is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your variables in

```
roles/<role_name>/defaults/main.yml
```

like:

```
SUPERVAR:
  VAR1:foo
  VAR2:bar
```

and then do in

```
roles/<role_name>/tasks/main.yml
```

like:

```
- fail: msg="{{ item }} is not defined"
  when: not {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - SUPERVAR.VAR1
    - SUPERVAR.VAR2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mandatory-values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-mandatory-values)

> If you configure Ansible to ignore undefined variables, you may want
> to define some values as mandatory. By default, Ansible fails if a
> variable in your playbook or command is undefined. You can configure
> Ansible to allow undefined variables by setting
> DEFAULT_UNDEFINED_VAR_BEHAVIOR to false. In that case, you may want to
> require some variables to be defined. You can do this with:
>
> {{ variable | mandatory }}